# Error: The best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments and Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a "date" column in Database table whose datatype is "datetime".

I want to insert the current date & time into it.
I am using below code:

**Default.aspx.cs code**

```
protected void btnInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    SDM.Invoice.InsertInvoice(date);
}
```

**"SDM.Invoice.cs" class code**

```
protected SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoiceTableAdapter Adapter
{
    get
    {
        if (_GenerateInvoiceTableAdapter == null)
          _GenerateInvoiceTableAdapter = new SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoiceTableAdapter();

        return _GenerateInvoiceTableAdapter;
    }
}

public string InsertInvoice(DateTime Date)
{
   string query = Convert.ToString(Adapter.InsertInvoice(Date);
   return query;
}
```

when I run my Project after deploying on server, it gives me below error:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'*

I tried to modify my code as below:

```
protected void btnInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    SDM_Invoice.InsertInvoice(Convert.ToDateTime(date));
}
```

again when I run my Project after deploying on server, it gives different error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'SDM_Invoice.InsertInvoice(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments.

**Modified Code:** 
Now I am trying to save it into Database using Stored Procedure. 
Code is as below:

```
protected void btnInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[SDM_Insert_Invoice]";
        cmd.Connection = con;     

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);               

        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();        
    }
```

*Stored Procedure:*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SDM_Insert_Invoice]  
     @Date as datetime,     
    AS  
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    INSERT INTO dbo.SDM_Tran_GenerateInvoice
    VALUES (@Date)
END
```

*Now I get this error:*
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I tried all the possible ways suggested by everyone but still unable to save date. Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass like below code, There is no need of conversion...

```
protected void btnInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SDM_Invoice.InsertInvoice(DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
```

You have to make sure that the `SDM_Invoice.InsertInvoice` method is accepting a `DateTime` object type as the first parameter (which is clearly true because of the error message your server gives)

re-build your project and give it another try.

Comment: Why you converting in string if you want to store value in datetime variable. Remove "Tostring()" from DateTime.Now

Comment: @Rami, @Tonny : thank you for the reply. I tried `DateTime date = DateTime.Now` but then it is showing me 2nd error `The best overloaded method match for 'SDM_Invoice.InsertInvoice(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments`. What am I missing now ?

Comment: @user3196511 have you re-built your project? I would suggest you `clean' (right click--> clean) then re-build it. 
Try it locally before you deploy it to your server, that would be the safest and easiest approach to follow

Comment: @Rami: Actually the project with full code is already deployed at the staging server. Also, code is not on my local machine so can not clean and can not re-built it. Just I had added the button click function locally and pasted my code directly to the server (in already existing .aspx.cs page) along with the class file code. Please help me how to resolve it.

Comment: the server does not read code from `.cs` files anymore. At this point your code has been compiled into `yourProjectName.dll`. To resolve this you need to add your code to the latest version of the project then build and deploy it again. If it's a personal project I would have told you to rebuild the project with the new code and then replace the dll in the hosting server. you still need the `.aspx` page to be there too

Comment: @Shirish: Thankyou for the help but still not working. 
I had modified my posted question. Please check it. I am using Stored Procedure to save date in Database.but it gives me error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: @Rami: Please check the "modified code" section in my posted question. Please suggest what shall I change now to make it work. This code is running on my local machine.